# Data not appearing in dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net

Now I have double checked this, I have found it was just bad positioning, but now I am coming up with the error of the data not being added to the box and it's just displaying blank on the page, not even the "empty" text is appearing in it but the data is being found as it is displaying when I am debugging and hitting the adding part

```
public class BrandDropDownList : DropDownList
{

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        BrandListRetrieve();
        base.OnLoad(e);
    }

    public void BrandListRetrieve()
    {
        var factory = new BrandFactory();
        var customBool1State = factory.ByCustomBoolean1(true, CoreHttpModule.Session);

        if (customBool1State != null)
        {
            var brandDropDown = CoreHttpModule.Session.CreateCriteria(typeof(Brand)).List<Brand>();
            DropDownList brandDropDownList = new DropDownList();

            foreach (Brand brand in brandDropDown)
            {
                brandDropDownList.Items.Add(brand.Name);
            }

            if (brandDropDownList.Items.Count < 0)
            {
                brandDropDownList.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Hello World", "Hello World"));
            }

            brandDropDownList.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

The ASP.NET

```
<needlesports:BrandDropDownList runat="server" Visible="true"  />
```

Comment: Since you're adding the items directly to the DropDownList, I dont' think the DataBind() step is necessary.

Comment: Hey, I've actually just removed this :) I noticed that myself but it doesn't appear to make any difference, I will double check to see.

Comment: Do you know that WPF aka Windows Presentation Foundation is not equal to ASP.NET Webforms? Please re-tag your question.

Comment: Hey, sorry I don't know why I put WPF... I didn't actually meant to!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need this line;

```
      DropDownList brandDropDownList = new DropDownList();
```

There is no need to be creating a new instance of a `DropDownList` within a `DropDownList`.

You should be just doing this;

```
this.Items.Add(brand.Name);
```